# Can I install Mandriva Linux One inside Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, linux-mint, mandriva

I'm a long time user of Linux Mint KDE and recently i heard about Mandriva and downloaded it.
I've used Linux Mint within Windows. (On autorun, it has an option "install inside windows")

On Uninstalling it, there's no boot problems.

Can I do the same for Mandriva Linux One? There's no such option.
Because , I don't want to have Grub as main bootloader - When I uninstall it in the future, "grub rescue" will come and scare me...

Comment: I don't think so, but perhaps you should give Ubuntu a shot. It has a feature where you can install it on a Windows partition too.

Comment: I've used it previously . Linux Mint is an ubuntu flavor and i want a switch from it .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) to run Mandriva.

Comment: thanks . but i've used both virtual box and vmware before ! .